# Laptop ASUS X75VD kernel 5.4.0-29 no sound no network

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, asus

My Kubuntu just updated to kernel 5.4.0-29, and I now have no sound, no wifi.
Booted with kernel 5.4.0-28 - all works.
Laptop ASUS X75VD.

dpkg -l | grep linux

```
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                     2.34-6ubuntu1                               amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                           1.194ubuntu3                                all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                             3.0-1build2                                 amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                                1.18.0-2build1                              amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                          1.18.0-2build1                              amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu3                                  all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                1.187                                       all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-26                        5.4.0-26.30                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic                5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-28                        5.4.0-28.32                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic                5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-29                        5.4.0-29.33                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic                5.4.0-29.33                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                         5.4.0.29.34                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic                  5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-28-generic                  5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           5.4.0.28.33                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-29-generic         5.4.0-29.33                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic                5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-28-generic                5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic                5.4.0-29.33                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic          5.4.0-26.30                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-28-generic          5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-26-generic     5.4.0-26.30+2                               amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-26
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-28-generic     5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-29-generic     5.4.0-29.33                                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-29
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04    5.4.0-29.33                                 amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-390 for generic-hwe-20.04
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                        all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                    1.10.0-1build1                              amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                      3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2         amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                               3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2         all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                               2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                        amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                    2.34-0.1ubuntu9                             amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

Comment: They maybe two reasons: 1)the new kernel wasn't fully installed, `modules` package didn't; 2) it is some kernel bug. Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux`.

Comment: Added output info.

Comment: How did you upgrade kernel. It seems that you did it manually and wrong. Or enabled `proposed` repo. The current kernel is `5.4.0-28`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reaon you don't have `linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic` and `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic`.

`linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic` contains device drivers.

Most likely the upgrade was interrupted.

I suggest running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
```

But the current kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 is `5.4.0-28`. You could get the 5.4.0-29 kernel only by installing packages manually (not all of them), or by enabling the `proposed` repository, that is not recommended and can cause problems.

The `proposed` repo is not supposed for full upgrades. It is needed for testing of specific packages. It should be disabled.

I suggest installung `synaptic` and removing all `5.4.0-29` kernel packages.

Comment: Yes, I enabled this repository. I can turn it off, but how to delete all that was installed from it?

Comment: It is not easy to remove. You can install `synaptic` and filter by source. But it is easy enough to disable the repo and remove only kernel 5.4.0-29 packages. Hopefully everything else will be fixed by itself by future updates.

Comment: The system is just installed. I think it's easier to reinstall it. Thank You for help!